# Como eliminar a mensagem "A execução do código foi interrompida." em VBA

Tags: vba

Quando estou executando uma macro VBA, eventualmente o código é interrompido, como se houvessem breakpoints.

A mensagem exibida é:

> A execução do código foi interrompida.

Se aceitar a mensagem e continuar a execução do código, o comportamento se repete se a macro for longa (procedimento com muitas linhas ou laços longos).

A interrupção acontece em diversos locais.

Como posso evitar/resolver esse comportamento?

Answer (score 1):

Insira as expressões abaixo no seu código:

```
Application.EnableCancelKey = wdCancelDisabled

(... code ...)

Application.EnableCancelKey = wdCancelInterrupt
```

Comment: Legal a sua participação e ajuda. Fica a dica de [edit] a resposta e dar uma pequena complementada explicando o que causa o problema e como a solução resolve, isso valorizaria bastante a postagem. E seja bem-vindo ao SOpt!